# Effectively defunct PGN player due to game length

Tags: bug, pgn-viewer

The PGN player is practically unusable if the game is too long. This causes the controls to be two meters under the board, forcing me to scroll back and fro until the cows come home.

This is solely due to my system being older than me, thus my monitor runs on 1024x768, and the column space for the game moves isn't even wide enough for one move. (On 1280x1024 it works fine, but I neither will switch that each time *just* for CSE.)

Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Your remark regarding monitor size (in pixels) is a good one. Other users who need such resolution are those with visual impairments.